# array of image pixels and their color

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a grayscale image, I would like to split it into pixels and determine the grayscale in each pixel of the image.
The array is needed in the following form: (pixel by X, pixel by Y, gray shade 0-255).

`1,1,25;`

`1,2,36;`

`1,3,50;`
.
.
.

`50,60,96;`
.
.
.
if the image is 500 by 600 dots, then at the end it should get - (500,600, grayscale).

Could you tell me please, how can I get such an array of data from an image? What do I need to do? Which libraries should I use? If there is someone who has solved such a problem, please give an example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an image file, you can read it like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/path/to/image.png')
```

To get this an an array:

```py
import numpy as np

ima = np.asarray(img)
```

If it's really an 8-bit greyscale image, you might be able to use `Image.open('image.png', mode='L')`, but in any case you can always just get the red channel with `ima[:, :, 0]`. If it's greyscale, all the channels will be equal.

Now you can stack these grey levels with the coordinates:

```py
h, w, _ = ima.shape
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(w), np.arange(h))
np.dstack([x, y, ima[..., 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(10)
img = np.random.randint(0,256, (500,600))

# coordinates
# np.meshgrid is also a good (better) choice
x, y = np.where(np.ones_like(img))

# put them together
out = np.stack([x,y, img.ravel()], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[  0,   0,   9],
       [  0,   1, 125],
       [  0,   2, 228],
       ...,
       [499, 597, 111],
       [499, 598, 128],
       [499, 599,   8]])
```

Comment: A wonderful example, illustrative. Thanks! But I would need more specifically, without randomness, but with a real picture. Thanks!